# Error "cordova build android"

Tags: android, cordova

OS: Linux Mint

Android Stubio 2.3.3

Cordova: 6.5.0

java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

All settings are registered, but the build does not work.

```
# cordova requirements android

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17,android-16,android-15,android-14,android-13,android-12,android-11,android-10,android-9,android-8,android-7
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
```

All settings are registered, but the build does not work.

```
# cordova build
ANDROID_HOME=/home/mark/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_5o0xmdzdvkp7hxld5azt4w1sx.run(/home/mark/helloBook/platforms/android/build.gradle:137)
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources/home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: 1: /home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.749 secs
Error: /home/mark/helloBook/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: 1: /home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Help to solve the problem. It's already the 4th day that you can not create a .apk file.

Thank you.

UPD: All my way.

```
mark mark # cordova create myBoo org.apache.cordova.myBoo myBoo
Creating a new cordova project.
mark mark # cd myBoo
mark myBoo # cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: org.apache.cordova.myBoo
    Name: myBoo
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving android@~6.2.3 into config.xml file ...
mark myBoo # cordova requirements android

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17,android-16,android-15,android-14,android-13,android-12,android-11,android-10,android-9,android-8,android-7
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
mark myBoo # cordova build android --verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/assets/www
Wrote out android application name "myBoo" to /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (1.0.0): 10000
Wrote out Android package name "org.apache.cordova.myBoo" to /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/myBoo/MainActivity.java
This app does not have launcher icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=/home/mark/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Running command: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle -p /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android wrapper -b /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle
:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 21.872 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Command finished with error code 0: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle -p,/home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android,wrapper,-b,/home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Running command: /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_4oytre40bj110004xk7skx6js.run(/home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/build.gradle:137)
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources/home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: 1: /home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 9.742 secs
Command finished with error code 1: /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
Error: /home/mark/myBoo/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: 1: /home/mark/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: One of your requirement does not work properly , Cordova perhaps , Try to uninstall and reinstall it again using NPM , and try to build from a new cordova project directory,

Comment: @AliEsmaeili error. I add upd.